# Why is manoeuvring speed higher in utility category?

Tags: aircraft-performance, stall, weight-and-balance, aircraft-limitations, v-speeds

In a C172P, the manoeuvring speed is 99 KIAS at 2400 lbs, 92 KIAS at 2000 lbs, and 82 KIAS at 1600 lbs. However, it is 102 KIAS at 2100 lbs when in the utility category, which has a more restrictive aft C of G limit.

Why the increase in $V_a$? My guess is that not allowing such an aft C of G in utility category allows the higher manoeuvring speed because this also restricts how low the stall speed could get. Is this correct?

Answer (score 9):

There are three factors: Va speed, weight, and CG limit.

Va is connected to the weight limit, not to the CG limit.  If you look at a typical V/G diagram, you'll notice that Va is defined by the load factor **at max gross**. Multiplying the load factor times the weight gives the force exerted on the structure at Va.

In the case of the 172, in the normal category at max gross is 3.8G * 2400# = 9120 pounds.

In the utility category 4.4G * 2100# = 9240 (about the same as 9120).

So if the weight is limited to 2100#, the G load can be increased to 4.4, and not exceed the overall structural limits of the aircraft.

The CG limit in the utility category is there to ensure that the CG is forward enough that the pilot can more easily recover from the maneuvers, such as stalls and spins. It probably has a lot to do with the amount of elevator authority, which is necessary to break the stall.

[image]

Comment: Oh wow. I totally ignored the higher load limits. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think answer is simple. In utility category limit factor is higher: +4.4g. Normal category: +3.8g. You have higher limit factor so you have higher speed.